# How to dockerize drupal 8 multi-site on local development?

Tags: php, docker, drupal, docker-compose, drupal-8

I'm trying to containerize my existing drupal 8 multi-site using docker. I'm basing my docker-compose file on [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal). I'm also following docker4drupal [More Multisite Questions #299](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/issues/299) but still unable to resolve my drupal 8 multi-site using only one database on my Mac OS local development. I'm following this Drupalize.me [Dockerize an Existing Project](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/dockerize-existing-project?p=3040) to containerize my existing drupal 8 multi-site and using Wodby's [Deploy all sites in one instance](https://docs.wodby.com/stacks/drupal/#deploy-all-sites-in-one-instance) documentation on setting up my current multi-site.

I'm able to access portainer.localhost, whoami.docker.localhost, pma.localhost, mailhog.localhost, and traefik (localhost:8080/dashboard/). What I cannot access are: reverse-proxy.drupalsites.localhost, php.drupalsites.localhost, mariadb.drupalsites.localhost, and localhost. The error that shows on the page when I access is "404 page not found". The error for accessing localhost is "File not found."

Here's my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./db-backups:/var/lib/backups:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
    volumes:
      - ./docroot:/var/www/html:cached

  nginx:
    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
#      NGINX_PAGESPEED: "on"
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
    volumes:
      - ./docroot:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=mailhog'
      - 'traefik.port=8025'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_pma"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: $DB_HOST
      PMA_USER: $PMA_USER
      PMA_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
      - 'traefik.port=80'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
    ports:
      - "8001:80"

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=portainer'
      - 'traefik.port=9000'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik #The official Traefik docker image
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api --docker #Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80" #The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" #The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events

  whoami:
      image: emilevauge/whoami # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
```

And this is my environment variables.

```
#Set environment default values for each site in multi-site

###PROJECT SETTINGS
PROJECT_NAME=docker-project
PROJECT_BASE_URL=localhost

DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
DB_NAME=example
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASSWORD=654321
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_DRIVER=mysql
PMA_USER=admin

### --- MARIADB ---
MARIADB_TAG=10.3

### --- Drupal 8 ---
DRUPAL_TAG=8-7.2-4.6.0

### --- PHP ---
PHP_TAG=7.2

### -- NGINX ---
NGINX_TAG=1.15
```

Comment: I wonder if the volumes for php container should be - drupal-install:/var/www/html instead of my current setting above. Since there is no drupal 8 installed yet in the database, I wonder if this is a necessary step first.

Comment: Okay, I'm able to access all the containers except localhost or any of my multi-sites. I tried site1.localhost and site2.localhost but all show 404 page not found error.

Comment: hello. do you figure this issue ? I'm insteresting in.